# Regular Expression capturing records PHP 2

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to get the result below, but I can not, could someone give me an idea?

My Cod.:

```
$string ='ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi                   ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu                 ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet,                   ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut';

if(preg_match_all("/ZAMM.*/", $string, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $match){
      echo $match;
      echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
1: ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi                   ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu                 ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet,                   ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut

2: ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet,                   ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut

3: ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet,                   ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut
```

Comment: I don't see the input data for 2 & 3, furthermore it seems like the input of 1 is similar as the output. So why do you even try to match something ?

Comment: I wanted to return line by line, to treat them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/ZAMM(.(?!ZAMM))*/
```

Take all following characters that are not followed by *ZAMM*. This is called *Negative Lookahead*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use look-aheads for this kind of thing. The pattern you need looks like this:

```
/ZAMM.*?(?=(ZAMM|$))/
```

This is where regex starts to get complex. The idea is that you're matching a string, but also looking ahead in the string to find the end point of the match. You can find out more about this and other advanced regex syntax here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

You also need to make the existing `.*` into a "non-greedy" pattern, by adding a question mark, otherwise it'll keep going to the end of the string on the first match (as it is doing already).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is "greedy", so the first match will consume the entire rest of the string. Try `.*?` instead, to make it non-greedy.

Comment: /ZAMM.*?/ but he did not return text.